# PHP regex replace white space by &nbsp; if it is following single letter

Tags: php, regex, replace

I have user defined string (html formated string to be saved and used in web) and need to find a way to replace each white space which is right after a single letter by `&nbsp;`.

For example `"this is a string"` should become `"this is a&nbsp;string"`,

`"bla bla b l abla b la blabla"` should become `"bla bla b&nbsp;l&nbsp;abla b&nbsp;la blabla"` ...etc...

Comment: What about single letters outside the ASCII alphabet? `"Allons à la plage?"` - or even `"Allons &agrave; la plage?"`

Answer (score 5):

```
preg_replace('/(?<=\b[a-z]) /i', '&nbsp;', $s);
```

The regular expression here performs a [*positive lookbehind*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which ensures that the space is preceded by a single letter and a word boundary.

Comment: I suggest to replace `\s` with `\b`, which will work in this case `i am`

Comment: @Ivan: [urgh; I hate the @] Good point. I put `\s` there because I was still on the idea that a single letter at the very start doesn't count. But that was based on flawed other assumptions (and the weird formatting of the OP who put spaces all around the quotation marks ...)

Answer (score 2):

without regex

```
$str = "this is a string" ;
$s = explode(" ",$str);
foreach ($s as $i => $j){
    if (strlen($j)==1){
        $s[$i]="$j&nbsp;";
    }
}
print_r ( implode(" ",$s) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$str = 'your string';

$str = preg_replace(array('/ ([a-zA-Z]) /', '/^([a-zA-Z]) /', array(' $1&nbsp;', '$1&nbsp;'), $str);

?>
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

To preserve the white spaces and line breaks for a text originating from a database:

```
<pre>
echo nl2br(str_replace(' ','&nbsp', stripslashes( database_string )));
<pre>
```