# Replace spaces around hyphens with nbsp

Tags: php, regex

I'm in need of (probably) regexp (or two) to do following:

- replace every space after any single letter word with `&nbsp;`

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094751/php-regex-replace-white-space-by-nbsp-if-it-is-following-single-letter), however, if there's word with apostrophe (like there's), previous regexp 'thinks' that the 's' after the apostrophe is single letter (which is not right). I want/need the space ONLY after single letter, not any other letter (not after words, not after words with apostrophes)

I'd like someone skilled to update the previous answer with this after apostrophe catch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this meet your expectations?

```
/(?<=^\w) |(?<=\s\w) /
```

[See it here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2ua99)

`(?<=\s\w)` is a lookbehind, that checks if there is a whitespace and a word character before the whitespace. `(?<=^\w)` is to cover the case thats the single letter is the first in the string.

`\w` is containing also a `_`, if this is not OK than you can define your own character class like `[a-zA-Z]` or use the unicode stuff `\p{L}` together with the modifier `u`

Comment: Yes, this is totally 'rad' :D

Comment: Improved version that also matches at the start of the string: `/(?<=^\w) |(?<=\s\w) /`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
preg_replace('/(\S) ', '${1}&nbsp;', $mystring);
```

The `\S` matches any non-whitespace character.

Comment: Isn't this actually even worse, doesn't this replace every sinle space with &nbsp? I want to replace space ONLY after single letters.

Comment: Wait, didn't you say "every space after every single letter"? This regex is doing that I think, at least for a suitable interpretation of "every single letter"... Do you mean after every "single letter that is surrounded by whitespace"?

Comment: Well, then it's my fault, I meant 'every single letter word'. Sorry!

Comment: OK, I see - well, you already got better answers, so I hope you'll get it to work! :-)