# PHP regex replace white space by &nbsp; if it is following single letter, but without breaking html tags

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace

I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094751/php-regex-replace-white-space-by-nbsp-if-it-is-following-single-letter)

```
preg_replace('/(?<=\b[a-z]) /i', '&nbsp;', $s);
```

to handle the first part of what I need. It transforms

```
"hello, this is a beautiful day"
```

into

```
"hello, this is a&nbsp;beautiful day".
```

Unfortunately it also breaks some html tags if they're present in content.

```
"hello, this is a <a href="example.com">beautiful day</a>"
```

ends up as

```
"hello, this is a&nbsp;<a&nbsp;href="example.com">beautiful day</a>"
```

How can I regex this sentence into

```
"hello, this is a&nbsp;<a href="example.com">beautiful day</a>"
```

I also have to handle some latin-extended characters, so example text to fix is

```
Dziedziczenie dlugów spadkowych jest wciąż bardzo żywym tematem, pomimo korzystnej dla spadkobierców zmiany przepisów w 2015 roku, o której szerzej pisałem na blogu <a href="http://www.prawnik-katowice.pl/blog-prawniczy/dziedziczenie-dlugow-od-18-pazdziernika-2015-roku/">tutaj</a>.
```

Comment: Use DOMDocument and DOMXPath and replace each textNode.

Comment: Use this [`(?i)<\/?\w+[^>]*>(*SKIP)(?!)|\b[a-z]\b`](https://regex101.com/r/r8tG3w/1)

Comment: Thank you for this one. It handles English text well, but the project I'm working on involves some latin-extended characters and this regex matches them too. I've updated the main post with example text.

Comment: [Then check this.](https://regex101.com/r/r8tG3w/4)

Comment: Thanks for the updated version. I see it works in your example. I've tried it myself and I don't know why it doesn't work for me. Could you check [this example](https://regex101.com/r/TG0x9L/1)?

Comment: That's because space characters in your input string are not [Space `0x20`](https://unicode-table.com/en/0020/) character. Please Check my update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RegEx:

```
(?i)<\/?\w+[^>]*>(*SKIP)(?!)|\b(\p{Latin})\s
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/r8tG3w/6)

PHP code:

```
preg_replace('~</?\w+[^>]*>(*SKIP)(?!)|\b(\p{Latin})\s~iu', '\\1&nbsp;', $str);
```

*Note: watch the `u` modifier.*

### Breakdown

```
 (?i)               # Set case-insensitive flag
 <\/? \w+ [^>]* >   # Match opening / closing HTML tags 
 (*SKIP)(?!)        # Throw them away
 |                  # Or
 \b                 # Match a word-boundary position
 ( \p{Latin} )      # Capture a letter
 \s                 # Match a whitespace
```

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted ([how to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/335649)) if it solved your problem and up-vote it if it was helpful.